# kernelstub can't find kernel or initrd image on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: linux-kernel, intel, kvm, iommu

I'm trying to enable Intel_IOMMU with the --add-option flag for kernelstub, but the command always fails, returning that kernelstub cannot find the kernel image.

I tried to manually set the kernel path, but it then returns that it cannot find the initrd image, I do the same for that and it loops back to not finding the kernel image again.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I built kernelstub wrong. for it to work correctly install the pop! OS version one from here: https://github.com/pop-os/kernelstub